# Sending Form Data To SQL Then PDF

Tags: php, sql, forms

I have a form that I'm able to submit to an SQL or convert to a PDF for download, but I've had no luck getting it to do both.

Desired Behavior -> Form is submitted -> Data Sent to SQL -> User is directed to Populated PDF for download.

Current Behavior -> Form is submitted -> Data Send to SQL -> Nothing else happens

Here's the java code sending the form to multiple sources. Ideally I would like the form to submit, then redirect the user (without an iframe) to the pdf page.

```
<script language="javascript">
function OnButton1()
{
    document.Form1.action = "/sqlsubmit.php"    // First target
    document.Form1.target = "iframe1";    // Open in a iframe
    document.Form1.submit();        // Submit the page
    document.Form1.action = "/returnslip.php"    // Second target
    document.Form1.target = "iframe2";    // Open in a iframe
    document.Form1.submit();        // Submit the page
    return true;
}
</script>

<div style="visibility:hidden">
<iframe NAME="iframe1" WIDTH="40" HEIGHT="40"></iframe>
<iframe NAME="iframe2" WIDTH="40" HEIGHT="40"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way to do this is

> 1. Form is submitted and sent by ajax to the server
> 2. Data sent to SQL
> 3. The PDF file is generated and saved on server
> 4. Server send in response the link to the PDF
> 5. User redirects by the link to view and dowload the PDF

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return jFormer(this)">
...
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function jFormer(form) {

    var $form = $(form);
    var info  = $form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url:  'http://your-php.com',  // replace !!!
           data: info, 
           success: function(link) {
               window.location = link;  // Link to PDF, server responce 
           }
    });

    return false;

}
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['var_name1'])) {

    //1.  Insert to DB all you need
    //2.  Create PDF and save it

    echo $link; // Link to PDF

}
```

**NOTES**

- Use your way to insert to DB
- You can create PDF from html by external service API (like
  [pdfcrowd](http://pdfcrowd.com/))
- Making PDF takes time, about a min, so again, ajax will help you to get your user some feedback while processing on the server.
- You need jQuery in this solution.